# How do I find this HTML element with Python and Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selector

This is an excerpt from the HTML source:

```
<div class="flex items-center mt-4">
    <svg style="fill: var(--color-reptile);" viewbox="0 0 16 16" width="24">
```

I want to find the svg element. This works:

```
e = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.flex.items-center.mt-4 [style]')
print(e.get_attribute('style')) # prints 'fill: var(--color-reptile);'
```

But how would I find this element directly without addressing the parent? I tried `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('svg.fill\:.var\(--color-reptile\)\;')` or `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.var\(--color-reptile\)\;')`and all kind of different variations but every attempt just raises a "no such element" error.

Comment: Why are you not accepting answers?

Answer (score 0):

It case this is the only `svg` element on the page I guess the following `xpath` should work:
`//*[name()='svg']`
Since, surely, it's not the only `svg` on the page you should add some more details like:
`//*[name()='svg' and (@width='24')]`

Answer (score 0):

With css: `svg[style*="fill: var(--color-reptile);"]`, or `svg[viewbox="0 0 16 16"]`
The first one looks for svg containing a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this //*[local-name()='svg'] and grab the style attribute

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.` incorrectly. `.` indicates a class, not a style. That SVG does not have a class.

This CSS selector works

```
svg[style='fill: var(--color-reptile);']
```

but I would go with a variation of what you started with

```
div.flex.items-center svg
```

The style info on the SVG tag could easily change and then your locator is broken. It's less likely that the classes on the DIV parent will change and there's only one SVG child of that DIV so you should be good.